# GeoIP + Django, Invalid GeoIP city data file

Tags: python, django, geoip

This seemingly has no fix, I've read up on the previous bug which was apparently fixed 5 years ago [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11245). Basically I've done everything completely properly according to the documents in both [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) and at [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/install/city/).

I have specified my `GEOIP_PATH`, and have even tried specifying the files too using `GEOIP_CITY` but I still get the same traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/django/backend/apps/api/routes.py", line 98, in jsonp_wrapper
    resp = f(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/backend/apps/api/routes.py", line 205, in userLogin
    userProfile.updateLocation(request)
  File "/home/django/backend/apps/agents/models.py", line 89, in updateLocation
    location = locationFromRequest(request)
  File "/home/django/backend/apps/agents/models.py", line 29, in locationFromRequest
    return g.city(ip)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/base.py", line 159, in city
    enc_query = self._check_query(query, city=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/base.py", line 148, in _check_query
    raise GeoIPException('Invalid GeoIP city data file: %s' % self._city_file)
GeoIPException: Invalid GeoIP city data file
```

I'm just doing a simple test in a python shell to test using:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
g = GeoIP()
g.city('google.com')
```

`g.country('google.com')`  <--- this works fine, note this problem is only with the CITY db I guess

I did install the GeoIP C Library from apt, using `apt-get install libgeoip-dev`, which has apparently given me an older version `1.6.0-1` when the newest version is `1.6.2-1`. My Django version is 1.6.1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Django 1.6.5 is required.

Make sure to upgrade from 1.6.1, pip install django==1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

I was using Django 1.5 and I fixed this problem downloading and using the binary files from:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/